# how to static add openssl with c++ builder?

Tags: dll, openssl, static-libraries, c++builder

I am able to use openssl in the source code below, but without the libeay32.dll file, my project does not open. I want to add it static and eliminate the need for dlls. How can I do that ?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32.lib")
TForm1 *Form1;
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
BIO* key;
void* buf;
key=BIO_new_mem_buf(buf,100);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to compile statically but without success.

Comment: You need a static version of OpenSSL that is compiled with C++ Builder. Good luck finding one. You will likely have to compile OpenSSL's source code yourself. What is wrong with using DLLs? That is how OpenSSL is meant to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm looking for adventure myself and I'll rewrite the dll.

Comment: If you succeed let me know. Since they changed the linker in v11 I am having problems loading the dll's under certain circumstances, a static version would fix that. For now I work with 11 and link with 10 :/